# Lychee: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, nginx

I'm running [Lychee](https://lychee.electerious.com/) on my server (photo hosting software). Everything works fine except the image upload. I get the following error:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a
>   temporary file in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header
>   from upstream, client: 123.123.12.12, server: example.com,
>   request: "POST /php/index.php HTTP/2.0", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com", referrer:
>   "example.com/"
>
> 2017/07/27 08:03:51 [error] 10711#10711:
>   *183 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the
>   allowed path(s): (/var/www/) in Unknown on line 0

The error still exists after adding "/tmp" to "open_basedir"

```
open_basedir = "/var/www/:/tmp/"
```

And adding a tmp dir with www-http rights in /tmp

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/http-upload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the open_basedir parameter in nginx

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files  $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/var/www/:/tmp/";
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```